# Rails has_many through cannot save in nested form due to id = null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-and-belongs-to-many

Using Rails 4.1.13 and Ruby 2.0.0 (although I had the same problem with Ralis 4.0 and Ruby 1.9.3. I have read numerous articles about this particular issue and cannot understand why my solution (which seems exactly like [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through)) does not work, so please help me out.

I have two models BlogPost and Tag. A BlogPost can have many Tags and one Tag can have many BlogPosts. I connect them through a third model BlogPostRelation. Thus, this is my basic setup:

```
# blog_post.rb
has_many :blog_post_tag_relations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :tags, :through => :blog_post_tag_relations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :blog_post_tag_relations, :tags

# tag.rb
has_many :blog_post_tag_relations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :blog_posts, :through => :blog_post_tag_relations

# blog_post_tag_relation.rb
belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :blog_post  
validates_uniqueness_of :tag_id, :scope => [:blog_post_id]
validates :blog_post_id, :presence => true
validates :tag_id, :presence => true    
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag, :blog_post
```

I have a form for BlogPost, using Formtastic, where I create checkboxes for the BlogPost using:

```
<%= f.input :blog_title %>
<%= f.input :tags, as: :check_boxes, :collection => tags.order(:name) %>
```

The problem I have is that BlogPost is not saved before the Tags are added which causes an validation failure of blog_post_id not being present (which it isn't):

```
  Tag Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags"  WHERE "tags"."id" IN (678, 56)
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  BlogPost Exists (1.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "blog_posts"  WHERE ("blog_posts"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "blog_posts"."slug" = 'de22323' LIMIT 1
  BlogPostTagRelation Exists (1.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "blog_post_tag_relations"  WHERE ("blog_post_tag_relations"."tag_id" = 678 AND "blog_post_tag_relations"."blog_post_id" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "blog_posts"  WHERE ("blog_posts"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "blog_posts"."slug" = 'de22323' LIMIT 1
  BlogPostTagRelation Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "blog_post_tag_relations"  WHERE ("blog_post_tag_relations"."tag_id" = 56 AND "blog_post_tag_relations"."blog_post_id" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "blog_posts"  WHERE ("blog_posts"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "blog_posts"."slug" = 'de22323' LIMIT 1
   (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
```

It seems like the solution should be to use `inverse_of`, which I frankly don't understand to 100%. It should also be mentioned that I am not 100% sure on how to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` either for this type of issue. I have tried all different setups but as far as I understand the only place they should be is in the join model, BlogPostRelation, like this:

```
# blog_post_tag_relation.rb
belongs_to :tag, :inverse_of => :blog_post_tag_relations
belongs_to :blog_post, :inverse_of => :blog_post_tag_relations

validates_uniqueness_of :tag_id, :scope => [:blog_post_id]
validates :blog_post_id, :presence => true
validates :tag_id, :presence => true    

accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag, :blog_post
```

This doesn't work either and I am completely lost now in what to do.

- Most important: What should I do?
- Is inverse_of the solution to this problem? If so, how should I use it?
- Am I using accepts_nested_attributes_for correctly?
- Does it have to do with the naming of BlogPostTagRelation (should it have been called BlogPostTag instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the problem here is that you are validating on ids. Rails cannot validate that blog_post_id is present if the id is not known, *but* it can validate that blog_post is present.

So part of the answer at least is to validate the presence of the associated instance, not the id.

Change the validations to:

```
validates :blog_post, :presence => true
validates :tag      , :presence => true
```

I would always specify inverse_of as well, but I'm not sure it is part of this problem.

Comment: I knew it was something this simple! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Your model structure is okay.
2. There's one nifty way you can add tags to your posts after the post is created. You just need to use a model method for doing that.You do not need `inverse_of` . Here is how:

   In your view, add a custom attribute (all_tags).

   ```
   <%= f.text_field :all_tags, placeholder: "Tags separated with comma" %>
   ```

   You need to permit the parameter in the controller.
   In your Post model add these three methods:

   ```
   def all_tags=(names)
     self.tags = names.split(",").map do |name|
     Tag.where(name: name.strip).first_or_create!
    end
   end
      #used when the post is being created. Splits the tags and creates   entries of them if they do not exist. `self.tags` ensures that they tags will be related to the post.

   def all_tags
    self.tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
   end

    #Returns all the post tags separated by comma

   def self.tagged_with(name)
     Tag.find_by_name!(name).posts
   end
    #Returns all the posts who also contain the tag from the current post.
   ```

   [Here's a full implementation](http://www.sitepoint.com/tagging-scratch-rails/)
3. You are using `nested_attributes_for` correctly, but in this case, you are having models who just have a name and a belongs_to column, so using this is  an overkill.
4. You can call it a tagging, although there's no convention for naming. If you and other can understand it, it is fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this feels like something of a "hack" rather than the elegant Rails-solution I am looking for. I mean, my problem can't be so specific it will need a hack, right? Isn't there any Rails-way to do this?

Comment: I think this is a quite elegant way of dealing with tags. Leaves less code in the controller (and that shows a good coding style)  and uses less code in general.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it isn't atomic. The tags will be created even if the validation fails.

Comment: You can call the method if the parent object gets saved when you're writing your controller logic

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to use is a has_and_belongs_to_many (HABTM) association: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

This however assumes you do not want to do anything with the Relationship Model (blog_post_tag_relations in your case)

You would need only the following models and associations:

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :blog_posts
end
```

You would then have to rename your join table blog_post_tag_relations to blog_posts_tags, the alphabetical plural combination of the two models. Rails automagically looks up/uses that table seamlessly in the background. It will only have the relationship's foreign_keys:

```
create_table :blog_posts_tags, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :blog_post, index: true
  t.belongs_to :tag, index: true
end
```

Then your form just works:

```
<%= f.input :blog_title %>
<%= f.input :tags, as: :check_boxes, :collection => tags.order(:name) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
validates :blog_post, :presence => true
validates :blog_post_id, :presence => true, allow_nil: true #can ignore this
```

Comment: So it should only be present, if it's present? :)